# Fetching value from another software into c# and then showing it into asp.net label using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, label

I have one authoring software from which I am fetching value using Request.Form[] of asp.net. Value is fetched succesfully. But then I want to show the value in a asp.net Label. How to do it using javascript? Kindly instruct me, I am new into javascript and learning. I tried to write the below code in my .aspx file.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
<script type="text/javascript">
function text()
{
if (document.getElementById("Label1") == "")
{
document.getElementById("Label1")= testname;

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do you fetch value?

Comment: by Request.Form[]; in asp.net, and while debugging it fetches value successfully. But then I want to display that value in a label. But when I run, it only shows the label not value. I tried it using Label1.text=testname" but it is also not working. So, I thought to try javascript. Any suggestion?

Comment: remove javascript, it is not needed, you need to assign on server side via `Label1.text = ...;` how do you fetch value? give at least 1 line of code

Comment: What you mean to say is on coding side, after fetching value, you are not able to store that value in label? Is your label in updatepanel?

Comment: I tried that before. First I wrote the code in .aspx.cs page in Page_Load(). Code was like below.
 string testname = Request.Form["TestName"]; 
 Label1.Text = testname;
Then I debug it line by line using F10, so hovering mouse on the code, it was showing the desired values. But when debug completed, it doesn't show fetched value that is "Test 1" in Label1 but just saw "Label1".

Comment: @HarshilRaval Yes, I am not able to store that value in label.